# Python - Remove newline before a line?

Tags: python, regex, replace, newline

I've managed to remove lines based on digits, and used another stackoverflow user's suggestion to replace **`\n`** and **`\r`** with ''...

**How to preserve a newline before a certain line with certain characters**?

I want to turn:

```
1
00:00:01,790 --> 00:00:03,400
\>> Hello there!
2
00:00:03,400 --> 00:00:05,140
\>> Hi you!
3
00:00:05,140 --> 00:00:07,600
\>> Important things that I am saying and 
should be a complete sentence or paragraph! 
!
 4
 This line is the start of a new paragraph
 That isn't delimited by any sort of special characters
```

into

```
\>> Hello there!
\>> Hi you!
\>> Important things that I am saying and 
should be a complete sentence or paragraph!! 
 This line is the start of a new paragraph
 That isn't delimited by any sort of special characters
```

so far I can get:

> >> Hello there! >> Hi you! >> Important things that I am saying and 
>   should be a complete sentence or paragraph!! This line is the start of a new paragraph
>   That isn't delimited by any sort of special characters

using

```
print "Please enter full filename with extension"
file = raw_input("> ")
with open (file, "r") as myfile:
    data=myfile.readlines()
x = ''
for line in data:
     if line[:1].isdigit() == False:
        x += line

y = ''
for line in x[1:]:
    if line[:2] == '>>':
        y += line.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
    else:
        y += ("\r" + line)


file_ = open('finished.txt', 'w+')
file_.write(y)
file_.close()
```

...where do I go from here?

Comment: Could you check if your question was properly edited please? Usually, it's better to use code formatting than quote formatting to avoid characters from disappearing (e.g if you have more than one newline in quote formatting, only 1 will be displayed, but that's not the case with code formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in x[1:]:
    if line[:2] == '>>':
        y += line.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '') + '\n'
    else:
        y += ("\r" + line) + '\n'
```

Try this by adding a '**`\n`**' behind.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the below portion of your code. Without these lines your code works correctly:

```
#Remove these lines
y = ''    
for line in x[1:]:
    if line[:2] == '>>':
        y += line.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
    else:
        y += ("\r" + line)
```

Here is a demo of rest of your code:

```
>>> fp=open('a','r')
>>> data=fp.readlines()
>>> data
['1\n', '00:00:01,790 --> 00:00:03,400\n', '\\>> Hello there!\n', '2\n', '00:00:03,400 --> 00:00:05,140\n', '\\>> Hi you!\n', '3\n', '00:00:05,140 --> 00:00:07,600\n', '\\>> Important things that I am saying and \n', 'should be a complete sentence or paragraph! \n', '!\n', '4\n', 'This line is the start of a new paragraph\n', "That isn't delimited by any sort of special characters\n"]
>>> x = ''
>>> for line in data:
...      if line[:1].isdigit() == False:
...         x += line
... 
>>> fp.close()
>>> print x
\>> Hello there!
\>> Hi you!
\>> Important things that I am saying and 
should be a complete sentence or paragraph! 
!
This line is the start of a new paragraph
That isn't delimited by any sort of special characters

>>> fp.close()
```

Now replace the below three lines:

```
file_ = open('finished.txt', 'w+')
file_.write(y)
file_.close()
```

with:

```
>>> file_=open('finished.txt','w+')
>>> for line in x:
...    file_.write(line)
... 
>>> file_.close()
```

This will fix the issue.